# Jenkins pipeline parameter code for multiple active choices

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For Active choice parameter Jenkins pipeline code

Project:

```
         []project1
         []project2
         []project3
         []project4
```

[] is a checkbox, we can select single or multiple projects.
I need the pipeline parameter code to bring this in Jenkins build parameter tab.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you achieved so far? Please show your code. I'm sure, you've search the web a bit and at least found a starting point like [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines) or [that](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines).

Comment: pipeline{
 parameters {
  choice(choices: 'abc\ndef\nghi\njkl', description: 'Select your choice', name: 'Choice')
 }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
    echo "Selected choice ${params.Choice}"
            }
        }
 }
}
This above code is for single choice, I need the code for multiple choices selection in the pipeline parameters.

Comment: See if Blue Ocean has that support (GUI way) and then if it generates the Groovy code for the pipeline for free. Otherwise, like StephenKing said, google it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Active choice parameter plugin, please refer this article on medium which can tell you step by step how to build using checkboxes under active choice parameter.

[Jenkins Active Choice parameter usecase](https://medium.com/the-devops-ship/jenkins-use-cases-series-use-active-choice-parameter-plugin-for-parameterized-build-with-values-3d87bccb3330)

You can use bash shell to define the logic of the user input, by just using the variable as the parameter name. Put them inside a loop if you running a build script which has to applied to all the options selected.

```
IFS=","
#user choices value will be a comma separated value 
domain=$YOUR_ACTIVE_CHOICE_PARAMETER_NAME

# get length of an array
names=($domain);

arraylength=${#names[@]}


# use for loop to read all values and indexes
for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ )); do

    echo "==========="
    <Your logic for build process>
    echo "==========="

done
```